# How to convert CSS attribute for image into HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image where the css is `background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`. However, when I place this in `<div style="background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;">` it doesn't work. What is the issue?

Comment: Presumably the relative URL to the image is wrong.

Comment: I have changed that and seen. The image comes on but is centered and does not display properly

Comment: Could you attach a fiddle or pen? To illustrate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're forgetting to write a semicolon after each style property, therefore your code is interpreted as a single property, which it is not.

My solution:

```
background: url(YOURURL);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
position: fixed;
```

Note: I assumed you wanted the entire div to remain in a fixed position.

Comment: Probably wanted background-attachment:fixed;

Comment: The OP is using the background property shorthand. OP's syntax is correct